# CSS Grid Implicit Row Height

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-grid

- I've created a CSS grid which initially has two columns of equal width as shown in the code below.
- However upon resizing, the implicit rows that are created do not have the same height even after using the grid-auto-rows property.

**HTML**

```
const Landing = () => {
  return (
    <section id="home" className="landing">
      <div className="landing__content">
        <div>
          <h3 className="subheading-default"></h3>
          <h1 className="primary spancolor-red"></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <figure className="landing__imagecontainer">
        <img src={require("../../assets/images/landing.jpeg")} alt="" className="landing__image" />
      </figure>
    </section>
  );
};
```

**SCSS**

```
.landing {
  height: 96vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(373.5px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  &__content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  &__image {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}
```

- Have tried using `auto` for `grid-auto-rows` as well.

Answer (score 0):

@krish,  element has default margin, so you need to remove it.
.landing__imagecontainer { margin: 0; }

```
.landing {
  height: 96vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(373.5px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  &__content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  &__imagecontainer {
    margin: 0;
  }

  &__image {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}
```

Hope it is helpful~